Facing issues while encrypting the data on nodejs side and then decrypting at reactjs and also vice-versa
I am implementing encryption for API responses in a Node.js application and decrypting them on the React.js client side. While the encrypted data is being sent successfully, I am encountering an error during decryption.
The API response is being sent via middleware in this format:
{
    "iv": "b86861bbb4753e9dd05675aab83a14ff",
    "encryptedData": "cfdsfwef8w9ehfnefnefklnflkwnflkewnewn"
}

However, while decrypting this on the React.js side, I receive the following error:
Decryption failed: Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

The error occurs at the line of code where the decrypted data is converted to a UTF-8 string:
const decrypted = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

What I have verified so far:
Matching Keys and IV: I’ve ensured that the encryption key and IV are the same on both the Node.js and React.js sides.
Hex Encoding: The key and IV are properly encoded in hex and parsed correctly in both environments.
Production Check: The encryption and decryption logic only runs in production, and I’ve confirmed that the isProduction flag is set correctly.
Despite these checks, the decryption fails.
Here is my code for both the Node.js side (encryption) and React.js side (decryption):
Reactjs side:
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { VITE_NODE_ENV } from './config';

// Check environment
const isProduction: boolean = VITE_NODE_ENV === 'development';

// Encryption key and IV setup
const key = isProduction
    ? CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('ce73fc57a80b6f7db56e16dd673ec9ebf8df9d35b648e9ac9bb353dd89772331') // Replace with your actual 256-bit key
    : null;

const iv = isProduction
    ? CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('b86861bbb4753e9dd05675aab83a14ff') // Replace with your actual 128-bit IV
    : null;

// Utility to decrypt data
const decrypt = (encryptedPayload: { iv: string; encryptedData: string }): Record<string, unknown> | null => {
    try {
        if (!isProduction || !key) return JSON.parse(encryptedPayload.encryptedData);

        const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedPayload.iv);
        const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedPayload.encryptedData, key, { iv });
        const decrypted = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        return JSON.parse(decrypted);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Decryption failed:', error);
        return null;
    }
};

export const getDecryptedResponse = (encryptedResponse: { iv: string; encryptedData: string }): Record<string, unknown> | null => {
    return decrypt(encryptedResponse);
};

Nodejs Side:
import crypto from 'crypto';
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
  const encryptionKey = isProduction
    ? Buffer.from('ce73fc57a80b6f7db56e16dd673ec9ebf8df9d35b648e9ac9bb353dd89772331', 'hex') // Replace with your actual key
    : null;
  const iv = isProduction
    ? Buffer.from('b86861bbb4753e9dd05675aab83a14ff', 'hex') // Replace with your actual IV
    : null;

  const encrypt = (text) => {
    if (!isProduction || !encryptionKey || !iv) return text;
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, encryptionKey, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted };
  };

  // Middleware to encrypt outgoing responses
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (isProduction) {
      const originalSend = res.json;
      res.json = (body) => {
        const encryptedBody = encrypt(JSON.stringify(body));
        originalSend.call(res, encryptedBody);
      };
    }
    next();
  });


CryptoJS requires the ciphertext in CryptoJS.AES.decrypt() either as CipherParams object or as Base64 encoded string, which is implicitly converted into a CipherParams object. You pass the ciphertext as hex encoded string, i.e. with an incompatible encoding.

Thanks! I have converted the hex part as base64. Now its working fine!

@VikasYadav add an answer if you have solved it.
